# How to Loop a simple program in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

I am trying to code a simple program in which the user can view and update a list of NBA player's racing for the MVP Trophy. However I have failed in the past to code a program in which can loop for however long the user decides to. I want the program to have the options 1. Go Back & 2. Exit but I cannot figure out how to loop it. Here is my Rank.java & AdminAccount.java. Hope it is not confusing to understand, thank you for reading.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rank {
    String player[] = { "Stephen Curry", "Russel Westbrook", "Kevind Durant", "LeBron James", "Kawhi Leonard" };
    Scanner rankInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner playerInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int rank;
    String playerUpdate;

    public void Rank() {
        System.out.println("Rank\tPlayer");
        for (int counter = 0; counter < player.length; counter++) {
            System.out.println(counter + 1 + "\t" + player[counter]);
        }
    }

    public void updateRank() {
        System.out.print("Select rank to update: ");
        rank = rankInput.nextInt();

        if (rank == 1) {
            System.out.print("\nPlayer Name: ");
            playerUpdate = playerInput.nextLine();
            player[0] = playerUpdate;
        } else if (rank == 2) {
            System.out.print("\nPlayer Name: ");
            playerUpdate = playerInput.nextLine();
            player[1] = playerUpdate;
        } else if (rank == 3) {
            System.out.print("\nPlayer Name: ");
            playerUpdate = playerInput.nextLine();
            player[2] = playerUpdate;
        } else if (rank == 4) {
            System.out.print("\nPlayer Name: ");
            playerUpdate = playerInput.nextLine();
            player[3] = playerUpdate;
        } else if (rank == 5) {
            System.out.print("\nPlayer Name: ");
            playerUpdate = playerInput.nextLine();
            player[4] = playerUpdate;
        }
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdminAccount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rank rank = new Rank();

        Scanner adminInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner exitInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean keepRunning = true;
        // menu variables
        int menuOption;
        int exitOption;

        while (keepRunning) {
            System.out.println("*** NBA MVP Race Administor Account ***");
            System.out.print("\n1.Ranking 2.Update\t- ");
            menuOption = adminInput.nextInt();
            System.out.println("");

            if (menuOption == 1) {
                rank.Rank();
            } else if (menuOption == 2) {
                rank.updateRank();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `if(1<=rank && rank<=5){System.out.print("\nPlayer Name: "); playerUpdate = playerInput.nextLine(); player[rank - 1] = playerUpdate;}` instead of the repetition of almost same code in `updaterank()`?

Comment: I will change it thank you.

Comment: "Hope it is not confusing to understand" It is confusing to understand. Can you please boil it down to the minimal code required to exhibit your problem completely? That would help you figure it out yourself as well, just try to write a program that only has the problem you're trying to solve and nothing about NBA players or anything else. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: why you need "Back" ? there is only one root menu

Comment: You are naming a class method "public void Rank()" the same as the class.  This leads to confusion with the class constructor, "public Rank()", and the method should be renamed to something else, possibly even "toString()".

Comment: I renamed it to rankList, would that be better, or toString()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an "exit" option to your loop:

```
while(keepRunning){
    System.out.println("*** NBA MVP Race Administor Account ***");
    System.out.print("\n1.Ranking 2.Update 3.Exit\t- ");
    menuOption = adminInput.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");

    if(menuOption == 1)
    {
        rank.Rank();
    }
    else if(menuOption == 2)
    {
        rank.updateRank();
    }
    else
    {
        keepRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to go back to the menu after updating both on AdminAccount.java & Rank.java ?

Comment: @L.Costa what do you mean "go back" it should re-display `System.out.println("*** NBA MVP Race Administor Account ***");
    System.out.print("\n1.Ranking 2.Update 3.Exit\t- ");` after your update/display...

Comment: Now I understand, it will keep looping until the user chooses exit. Thank you.

Comment: @L.Costa no problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

> **This a sample code using arrays**
> ***This Program Uses Do.... While Loop to Loop over a whole program when there is a user prompt.***

```
    package doWhileLoop;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class doWhileLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //this is a program to prompt a user to continue or pass using the do while loop
        String programCounter;
        do {
            int sum=0;
            int list[] = new int[3];
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter  3 numbers to be added: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                list[i] = in.nextInt();
                sum+= list[i];
            }
            System.out.println("sum = "+ sum);

            System.out.println("Enter Yes to continue or No to exit........");
            programCounter = in.next();

        }
        while (programCounter.equals("yes"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this is related to the given question